# Show that the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\nabla f(x)=0 \}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ convex function. Show that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\nabla f(x)=0 \}$ is convex (we assume that empty set is convex).

Any hint?

Comment: Not sure but I think this set is empty, $\mathbb{R}^N$ or contains only one $x$, because every $x$ in the set has neighberhood without other points of the set (continuity)

Comment: @Pollak: No. Consider for example $f(x,y) = x^2$.

Comment: You have been around for a while... you should know [How to ask a Good Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)... meaning not just with "Any hint? / Tips?" at the end... surely you thought about this problem before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convexity implies $f(y)\ge f(x)+\langle \nabla f(x),y-x\rangle$ for all $x,y$. Specializing this to the points of your set, you will find they are points where $f$ attains its global minimum, say $m$. Argue that $\{x:f(x)=m\}$ is convex.